# NServiceBus saga with local service commands

Tags: nservicebus

I've been thinking a bit about how to correctly use commands within a saga and the obvious answer seems to publish an event after the command has completed and for the saga to handle the event published. My problem with this is if that service is also responsible for the command it's not going to be able to subscribe to the event published and you also cannot send a reply within a command.

What's the correct approach for this? Request/Response, register to the command within the saga or something else I've not thought of?

**Use case:**

My saga is started when an order is first created and considered complete once successfully inserted into our accounting system. Between these points I request validation on the order as well as have a window period for a buyers remorse message in which to void the order, for this I have a time out in place.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're using the saga for in this case - can you describe the long-running process?

Comment: I've added my use case, thanks Udi.

Comment: OK - but I'm still not clear on the problems you mentioned in this sentence: "My problem with this is if that service is also responsible for the command it's not going to be able to subscribe to the event published and you also cannot send a reply within a command." Why would it not be able to subscribe to the event? Why would you not be able to send a reply from a command?

Comment: Apologies, for some reason I was sure NServiceBus would throw an error when doing this and suggest the use of IMessage so until I've just avoided doing so. Thanks!